# Should I try to amalgamate static bodies as much as possible?

Tags: c#, xna, farseer, 2d-games

Im making a roguelike game, using XNA and farseer physics.
Some rooms will have a procedurally generated cave like layout made from blocks.
[image: "caves" with farseer debug mode on]

At the moment every block is a seperate body. created thusly:

```
 _floor = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(_world,   ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(Globals.SmallGridSize.X), ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(Globals.SmallGridSize.Y), 30f);
        _floor.Position = ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(_position.X + _centerVect.X, _position.Y + _centerVect.Y);
        _floor.IsStatic = true;
        _floor.Restitution = 0.2f;
        _floor.Friction = 0.2f;
```

Should I Just have one body per room and add all the rectangle shapes for each block to the body?
Will this give me a performance boost? Also will it be possible to add and remove block shapes to this body (in order to be able to destroy a block and then "add" the exposed one behind it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will most likely want to retain having 1 Body per block, as it will be a lot easier for you to manage collisions when destroying a block.  Consider having to recalculate the shape of the 1 Body after a block is destroyed.  This would be quite taxing.

This is very similar to a game I have abandoned.  I originally had a Body for each block, which was very slow:

http://www.jgallant.com/images/uranus/land2.png

My first optimization was only setting Bodies on the edge of the generated world:

http://www.jgallant.com/images/uranus/chunk.png

This led to faster code, but there was still a problem with having too many bodies on screen.  My later optimizations added Bodies to the edges based on where the player was located on the world.  Bodies were pulled from a Pool of available bodies, and moved to the proper location.  Bodies were never destroyed, simply moved to Vector2(Int.Min, Int.Min) when not used.  When they needed to be used, they were moved to position:

http://www.jgallant.com/images/collision2.jpg

This provided the fastest code from the three methods.  If you are looking to destroy/create bodies on the fly, this is a really bad idea.  You are better off storing available bodies in a pool, and re-using them.

There are some complexities to this also.  I do not have my code handy at the moment, but if you have extra questions, I can post some of my code to help out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is so pertinent  :)  I think I will be able to implement your 3rd optimization easily enough.. Thats a clever solution!.. One thing I am now thinking about is how to deal with bullets in the game. I was thinking about using farseer for bullet collisions and having the bullets be kinematic bodies with no collision response or sensors.. But now I mite just do my own bullet collision system using something like this http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel_transformed..I may want 100's of bullets potentially I thnk it mite b fastr

Comment: I would suggest you use a Pool for your bullets as well.  I opted to not use Farseer for my bullet system, as it was a lot faster without it.  If you have very fast moving bullets, however, you may run into problems where the bullets pass through objects.

Comment: btw. If you look at my current screenshot, I have rooms that are 6 times that area (2x3) and I had all the blocks there and enabled. Also in the current build every room has these cave blocks but they are all just "disabled" for the non-current room.. I didnt have any performance problems with this on my craptop (I just want to make sure I dont get any) Atm Ive implemented something like your method 3 except the blocks just get enabled and disabled. It seems disabling saves the lions share of the processing power.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution for your scenario.  My world was infinite (in theory) in all directions.  Because of this, I needed to be able to recycle bodies in order to preserve memory.  Keep it up, I'd be interested in seeing what your final product will look like.

Comment: Thanks and yes definitely! Once I have a certain amount done I will put up a website. I can send you a link via this site.